# CUDA C programing guide: how do thread and block indexing calculations work?

Tags: cuda

in the CUDA_C_Programming_Guide,Chapter2,Thread Hierarchy

[image: relationship]

```
__global__ void MatAdd(float A[N][N],float B[N][N],float C[N][N]）  
{
  int i=blockId.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;  
  int j=blockId.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;  
  if(i<N&&j<N)  
    C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
}

int main()
{
....
  dim3 threadPerBlock(16,16);
  dim3 numBlock(N/threadPerBlcok.x,N/threadPerBlock.y);
  MatAdd<<<numBlocks,threadPerBlock>>>(A,B,C);
....
}
```

I'm a fresh man to this,can't make sense of "int i=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x".Why can be this?
Is there anyone can explain it to me? 
Thanks a lot.
For example,how to confirm the Thread(1,1) in Block(1,1) using "i" and "j"?

Comment: Code belongs inside the post itself. Do not post images of code.

Comment: picture one displayed the location relationship of block and thread

Comment: Picture 1 didn't load. Now it's picture 2.

Comment: picture 1 is code, now i post it out.(Sorry , fresh to use it

Comment: does titan xp have 1 grid or 6 grids?

Comment: Sir,i don't kown how much Titan X Pascal, my gpu is Tesla K10 and GTX980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer in the << CUDA Programming: A Developer's Guide to Parallel Computing with GPUs >> autor:Shane Cook.
In chapter 5,there is a clear explaination of that. 
As to 2D array, we need dim3 to create a 2D layout threads. 
"`dim3 threadPerBlock(16,16)`" means that a single block has 16 threads in its x axis and 16 threads in Y axis.
"`dim3 numBlocks(N/threadPerBlock.x,N/threadPerBlock.y)`" means that a single grid has N/threadPerBlock.x block along x axis and N/threadPerBlock.y along the y axis.
`gridDim.x` or `gridDim.y` means how many blocks along the x/y axis in a grid.
`blockDim.x` or `blockDim.y` means how many threads along the x/y axis in a block.
`threadIdx.x` or `threadIdx.y` means the thread index along the x/u axis in a block.
`blockIdx.x` or `block.idx.y` means the block index along the x/y axis in a grid.
so if we want to know the absolute thread index,we should know how many blocks behind current block and how many threads behind current thread (row*(sizeof(array_element)*width)))+((sizeof(array_element)*offset)). So we get `i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x` .
there is a picture show grid,block and thread dimensions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHrk.jpg)